# Jquery / Javascript Progressbar blue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, blur

I am trying to built a simple progressbar, but got some problems.

Html looks like this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%"></div>
</div>
```

And my javascript like this:

```
$("input").blur(function(){ 
    var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
    if($(this).val().length > 0 && !$(this).is("filled")) {
        progressbar.width(progressbar.width() + 40);
        $(this).addClass("filled");
    } else if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).is(".filled")) {
        progressbar.width(progressbar.width() - 40);
        $(this).removeClass("filled");
    }
});
```

So basically I write something in my input field and click out and my progressbar increases.

If the input field returns to empty after it was filled the progressbar decreases.

The problem is now that I keep clicking in and out on a not empty input and the progressbar keeps increasing.

Fiddle:

[Demo Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ur54g61b/)

Comment: it should be `&& !$(this).is(".filled")` in line 3, you missed a `.` (class selector notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1a8qcgdc/10/ and instead of:

```
var isfilled = 0;
```

I added a class nowFilled, hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  precheckConditions();
  addToProgressbar();
})

function precheckConditions() {
 var progressValue = 0;
  var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
  $('input').each(function() {  
      if ($(this).val()) {
        progressValue += 40;
        $(this).addClass('filled');
      }
  });
  progressbar.width(progressbar.width() + progressValue);
}


function addToProgressbar() {
  $('input').blur(function() {
    var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
    if ($(this).val().length > 0 && !$(this).is("filled") && !$(this).hasClass('filled')) {
      progressbar.width(progressbar.width() + 40);
      $(this).addClass("filled");
    } else if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).is(".filled")) {
      progressbar.width(progressbar.width() - 40);
      $(this).removeClass('nowFilled')
      $(this).removeClass("filled");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="project_name" placeholder="Placeholder" value='Pre added value'>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="asd" placeholder="Placeholder" value='Pre added second value'>
```

Comment: This works fine thanks, could you explain what I made wrong

Comment: You did nothing wrong if you only use one inputbox, but when you have multiple boxes you need to somehow check if that box has been edited or not. That is why i add a class to the specific inputbox that has been edited. Then in your first if-statment I check if the specified inputbox is filled or not.

Comment: How would you do this on empty inputs with placeholders

Comment: oh sorry, I do not mean placeholders I mean if an input already has an value like a name, I would like to immidietly increase the processbar, how would you manage this, currently it "ignores it";

Comment: Nice, but does not work on multiple inputs with values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109440/discussion-between-zorken17-and-john-does-legacy).

Comment: one last question -> chat

Comment: hi do you have time again?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
 function test() {
 var x = 0;
 $('input').each(function(){//change this with your input class
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    x++;
  }
 });
 return x
 }
$("input").blur(function(){
    var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
    var x = test();
    if($(this).val().length > 0 && !$(this).is(".filled")) {

        progressbar.width(40*x);
        $(this).addClass("filled");
    } else if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).is(".filled")) {
          progressbar.width(40*x);
        $(this).removeClass("filled");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1a8qcgdc/3/

Comment: strange, why is this happening?

Comment: @JohnDoesLegacy at what conclusion did you reach ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Check out the examples on the top right.

All options: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

```
$(function() {
  $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 37
  });
});
```